# How to get style attribute of iframe from inside of that iframe(javascript)

Tags: javascript, iframe, attributes, visibility

I'm trying to perform an action when iframe element is visible, but the iframe has style attribute where "visibiliy:hidden" is defined, this gives the output of iframe's :is('visible') as true, I'm not able to apply the visibility check because of this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to change the style property visibility and then perform the action. You will to run the code something like this.

```
let frame = document.querySelector("iframe");
   if (frame.style.visibility = "visible") {
    // Here you can perform required action
 }
```